# R run several functions on multiple columns based on binary column variable

Tags: r

I would like to know the most efficient technique to solve a recurrring issue.

I have many DBs in spreadsheet/csv format, that have this form (0,1 for T/F variables):

```
id_code, age,  heart_disease, weight, gender, operated, survived, ct_scan, days_hospitalized, 
1332,    43.2, 1,             213,    m,      0,        1,        1,       12
22322,   76.4, 0,             125,    f,      1,        0,        0,       45
995,     55,   1,             199,    m,      0,        1,        0,       34
```

In order to perform a t test on the continuous variables in, say, survivors vs non-survivors:

```
myfx1 <- function(x) {t.test((x), mydat$survived)}
myfx1(mydat$age)
myfx1(mydat$weight)
```

then I replace 'survived' with another variable and repeat.

In order to do contingency crosstabs in survivors vs non-survivors,

```
myfx2 <- function(x) {xtabs(~mydat$survived+x, data=mydat)}
myfx2(mydat$gender)
myfx2(mydat$operated)
```

I have tried **plyr** and **doBy**; the many examples always use mean/variance or other simple functions to demonstrate usage. What is the simplest most efficient way to process a large number of variables?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lovely little function in the `plyr` package that runs a function on a column by column basis.

```
colwise(myfx1)(your_db[,you_numeric_columns])
```

---

Update:

```
id_code <- sample(1:1000,500)
age <- sample(40:80,500, replace=T)
heart_disease <- sample(0:1,500,replace=T)
weight <- sample(105:250,500,replace=T)
operated <- sample(0:1,500,replace=T)
survived <- sample(0:1,500,replace=T)
ctscan <- sample(12:45,500,replace=T)

dat <- data.frame(id_code,age,heart_disease,weight,operated,survived,ctscan)

fx1 <- function(x) t.test(x, dat$survived)$p.value

colwise(fx1)(dat[,2:ncol(dat)])
```

Works for me... as an example.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this and variants (after looking up colwise) as seen below. None worked. The errors are printed with the attempt:

1. colwise(myfx1)(mydat[,2]) ->
Error: is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE

2. colwise(.myfx1, .mydat$age) -> 
Error in colwise(.myfx1, .mydat$age) : object '.age' not found

Comment: 3. colwise(.myfx1, mydat$age) -> 
function (df, ...) 
{
    stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
    df <- strip_splits(df)
    filtered <- filter(df)
    if (length(filtered) == 0) 
        return(data.frame())
    df <- quickdf(lapply(filtered, .fun, ...))
    names(df) <- names(filtered)
    df
}
<environment: 0x1055ab758>

4. colwise(myfx1, mydat$age)

same error as 3

4. colwise(myfx1)(mydat[,age]) ->
Error in `[.data.frame`(mydat, , age) : object 'age' not found

5. colwise(myfx1)(mydat[,mydat$age]) ->
Error in `[.data.frame`(mydat, , mydat$age) : undefined columns selected

Comment: 6. ddply(mydat, .age , colwise(myfx1)) ->

"Error in t.test.default((x), NEC$Survived) : not enough 'x' observations
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

7. ddply(mydat, , colwise(myfx1, age))

8. ddply(mydat, , colwise(myfx1, .age))